# Load a textfile to List View

Tags: vb.net, listview

I am trying to load a textfile to a Listview. I have Open File Dialog turned on and   Dim streamer As IO.StreamReader Below is my code and I believe it is correct but instead I get the error
"Error  1   Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'AddRange' can be called with these arguments:"    Then lists all my coding.

```
Private Sub Loadbtn_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Browse.Click
    OpenFD.ShowDialog()
    streamer = IO.File.OpenText(OpenFD.FileName)
    Dim mystring() As String = streamer.ReadToEnd.Split(vbNewLine)
    List.Items.AddRange(mystring)
End Sub
```

Comment: thats because there is no overload for `AddRange` which takes a string array.  Press F2 to look it up; `AddRange` takes a ListViewItem array or collection of them

Comment: F2 did not seem to do anything for me not sure why, however I tried googling some more information and it basically said to do it like this "List.Items.AddRange(New mystring())" but now it tells me that "Mystring is not defined"

Comment: is it a ListBox or a ListView? the syntax you give is for the former, but your question and title reference the latter.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.listviewitemcollection.addrange(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: ListView so I can have two columns as one side is going to be encrypted other is decrypted